# Python for loop within function multiple parameters

Tags: python, function, for-loop, str-replace

I'm currently stuck on a problem and looking for some community help.

I can't figure out this problem. Trying to replace {{ }} parameter within multiple strings with given dictionary values within a function.

Dictionary -

```
{'id' : 'nyc', 'weather':'sunny','id2':'bos','weather2':'snowy'}
```

string1 -

```
"""
It was {{weather}} in {{id}}
"""
```

string2 -

```
"""
It was {{weather2}} in {{id2}}
"""
```

Obviously a very simplified example...

for loop something like this -

```
def replace_params(qry):
    for k,v in qry_params.items():
        qry = qry.replace('{{'+k+'}}', v)
    
    return qry


replace_params(string1,string2)
```

So output becomes

```
"""
It was sunny in nyc
"""
```

I understand there are other approaches to this, but do need help with given problem using double {{ }}

Comment: @schwobasegglthat won't work due to the doubled curly braces.

Comment: unfortunately need those double curly brackets in there

Comment: the double curly braces, suggest `jinja2` template. Is that the case? If you want to do string formatting - use single curly braces.

Comment: `replace_params` has one argument defined, but you have passed two arguments when calling. Why is that?

Comment: Do you require an output like ''It was {{sunny}} in {{nyc}}'' ?

Comment: no the result would be "It was sunny in nyc"

Comment: Using `replace_params(string1)` on your function gives me 'It was sunny in nyc'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, double curly braces suggest `jinja2` template. You need yto install [jinja2](https://pypi.org/project/Jinja2/)

Then

```
from jinja2 import Template

data = {'id' : 'nyc', 'weather':'sunny','id2':'bos','weather2':'snowy'}

string1 = """
It was {{weather}} in {{id}}
"""

string2 = """
It was {{weather2}} in {{id2}}
"""

def render(values, *args):
    return [Template(arg).render(values).strip() for arg in args]

print(render(data, string1, string2))
```

Output

```
['It was sunny in nyc', 'It was snowy in bos']
```

All that said - if you really work with template - this is not how it should be, something like this

```
from jinja2 import Template

data = [{'id' : 'nyc', 'weather':'sunny'},{'id':'bos','weather':'snowy'}]
my_template = Template("It was {{weather}} in {{id}}")

def render(values, template):
    return [my_template.render(item) for item in values]

print(render(data, my_template))
```

You may have the loop inside the template.
But for something like this it's easier ti use single braces and `f-string` or `str.format()` instead of jinja tempalte.

Comment: if i use ```for k,v in qry_params.items():
string1 = string1.replace('{{'+k+'}}', v)``` without the function, i do not get \n but using the function i do , how come?

Comment: You do have new line, but you don't see it.  Anyway, use `str.strip()` method. I edited my answer